# catch 22 regarding gameobject and OnMessage in unity/c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

I am trying to catch a set of numbers from a websocket in unity and use it to update the orientation of a block. The problem is that if I tell it `GameObject _cube = GameObject.Find("MyCube");` after void Start(), then OnMessage doesnt know what _cube is. If I try to use GameObject.Find in OnMessage, then it complains that find can only be used in the main thread.

I am not sure how to untangle this.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;
using System;


public class WS_Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject _cube;

    public class MyWebSocketServer : WebSocketBehavior
    {

        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
        {

            string data = e.Data;
            string[] components = data.Split(' ');
            Debug.Log("splits components");
            float x = float.Parse(components[0]);
            float y = float.Parse(components[1]);
            float z = float.Parse(components[2]);
            Debug.Log("parses components");

            Vector3 vector = new Vector3((float)x, (float)y, (float)z);
            Debug.Log("puts them in vector3");
            try
            {
                _cube.GetComponent<Transform>().eulerAngles = vector;
                Debug.Log("rotates mycube");
                //_cube.transform.eulerAngles = vector;
                //           _cube?.transform.eulerAngles = vector;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.LogError("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }

        }
        protected override void OnOpen()
        {
            // Handle client connection here
            Debug.Log("someone connected");
        }
        protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Handle client disconnection here
            Debug.Log("someone disconnected");
        }
    }

    WebSocket ws;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 50.0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject _cube = GameObject.Find("MyCube");
        WebSocketServer wssv = new WebSocketServer(8080);
        wssv.AddWebSocketService<MyWebSocketServer>("/MyWebSocket");
        wssv.Start();
    
    }

}
```

Comment: Then it sounds like you declared _cube in the wrong place

Comment: I crammed the two classes together in hopes that it would let me declare it and see it (see code). Then I declared it on top.

Comment: You cant just put things in random places and hope. Especially as while you put it on top outside your class you redeclared (eg overrode) it with a local one in the start. So no. That wont work

Comment: what do you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest reading your data, and using an event (eg `Action<Vector3>`) to let your Unity based code know there’s a message ready, and use that data to manipulate your “cube” game object. Separation of concerns. Your cube doesn’t need to know where the data came from, and your “on message” code doesn’t need to know where the data is being used.

Comment: Ok, I managed to create a callback using action, but I am back to my original problem. The callback is not on the main thread and therefore cant use transform:
https://pastebin.com/Eb3qYUAB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

There is a slight race condition, but that is fine for my purposes. Basically the callback sends the data to the handle, and the handle just updates a local variable which is constantly being used in the main thread to transform my block.

```
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;
using System;

public class OrientationEvent
{
    public event Action<Vector3> OnOrientationUpdate;
}

public class WS_Client : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameObject _cube;
    private Action<Vector3> callback;
    WebSocket ws;
    [SerializeField] float speed = 50.0f;
    private Vector3 _orientation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

        _cube = GameObject.Find("MyCube");
        if (_cube == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("couldnt find MyCube at first");
        }

        WebSocketServer wssv = new WebSocketServer(8080);
        Action<Vector3> callback = HandleOrientationUpdate;
        MyWebSocketServer wsService = new MyWebSocketServer(callback);
        wssv.AddWebSocketService<MyWebSocketServer>("/MyWebSocket", () => wsService);
        wssv.Start();

    }
    public WS_Client(OrientationEvent orientationEvent)
    {
        callback = HandleOrientationUpdate;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        _cube.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(_orientation);
    }

    private void HandleOrientationUpdate(Vector3 orientation)
    {
        Debug.Log("tries to rotate mycube");
        Debug.Log(orientation);

            // Update the cube's orientation using the data from the event
                try
          {
            _orientation = orientation;
             Debug.Log("translates the orientation");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
          {
             Debug.LogError("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
          }
        

    }

}
public class MyWebSocketServer : WebSocketBehavior
{
    private Action<Vector3> callback;

    public MyWebSocketServer(Action<Vector3> callback)
    {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
    {

        string data = e.Data;
        string[] components = data.Split(' ');
        Debug.Log("splits components");
        float x = float.Parse(components[0]);
        float y = float.Parse(components[1]);
        float z = float.Parse(components[2]);
        Debug.Log("parses components");
        Vector3 orientation = new Vector3(x, y, z);

//        Vector3 vector = new Vector3((float)x, (float)y, (float)z);
        Debug.Log("puts them in vector3");
        try
        {

            callback?.Invoke(orientation);
            Debug.Log("invokes action");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.LogError("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
    protected override void OnOpen()
    {
        // Handle client connection here
        Debug.Log("someone connected");
    }
    protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Handle client disconnection here
        Debug.Log("someone disconnected");
    }
}
```